# Ad-hoc skipping tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow

and I would like to understand whether my use case is doable in Airflow.

In general, I'm more interested in the flow management capabilities of Airflow rather than the scheduling. We intend to use Airflow as flow management infra for an internal tool we are building, and in this tool DAGs will be triggered manually when needed.

The feature I'm looking for is the ability to start the execution from the X task.
Lets say my DAG contains 5 tasks, for most I'll start from the first one, but sometimes I'll need to start from the 3rd or 2nd, or any other task.

On top of that - lets say my DAG (DAG_A) triggers another team's DAG (DAG_B) as part of it's execution. Will I be able to start the execution from the 2nd task on DAG_B?
Lets say the DAG_A looks like this:
task1 > task2 > DAG_B > task3 > task4

Thanks!